# How to display and edit all Jupyter shortcuts in vscode (similar to typical `jupyter-notebook`)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

Within Visual Studio Code, I would like to be view and customize my Jupyter-notebook shortcuts 
e.g. `ctrl-shift-c` to clear cell content, etc. similar to what is available using the typical  browser-based interface.

However, I did not manage to find a way to do so.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py

Answer (score 6):

To extend on Oliver.R's answer.

Go to the keyboard shortcuts (with `Ctrl+K`, `Ctrl+S` or `Ctrl+Shift+P` and search for `Open Keyboard Shortcuts` and then search for `notebook` which should list all the available bindings for `Jupyter`.

Alternatively, you could search for the shortcuts themselves (using the record key feature) or just typing `ctrl+shift+c` which shows you all bindings for that particular keys.

Once you have found the keybinding you want to change. You can click on it and push `Enter` (or use the `Change Keybinding` button to the left of the column) to change it.

However, I am not sure, if all the listed shortcuts work / are implemented. For me, only a fraction of the listed keybindings actually work.

Answer (score 5):

In VSCode, the keyboard shortcuts (accessed by ctrl+K, then ctrl+S) in the namespace `python.datascience` (search it in the shortcuts window) relate to notebook management such as running cells. I believe these are the only available built-in options however, and your example of "clear cell content" does not appear to be available.

Comment: I had a look at `python.datascience`. I'm a bit doubtful if it has all the keyboard shortcuts listed. For example, it is possible to do "delete current cell" using `dd` when cell is focused or "Insert a new row below" using `b`.

Comment: An option is to search the keyboard shortcuts for `notebook`.
But I  don't think that all of the listed shortcuts do work at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The support for jupyter shortcuts improved greatly.

It is hard to search for available shortcuts in vscode as quite a few are reusing generic actions and names. For example, selecting a cell is called "list.expandSelectionDown", and moving coursor down "list.down", but moving cell down is "notebook.cell.moveDown".

The best I've come up with is to search for 'notebookEditorFocused' it is almost always used in 'when' section.
[image]

I've also looked up through github issues and code for some shortcuts. Here is how I've found a way to navigate headers with `cmd|ctrl` + `shift` + `.` + `up/down`. And an alternative to `ctrl` + `m` that merges cells.

[I've composed a list of Jupyter notebook shortcuts, that currently work in VSCode](https://gist.github.com/PiotrCzapla/d4ea5d48c9cef7262da951b03edef981), looking from the angle of using [nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai) with vscode.